# Placing Image within double column text without resizing

Tags: floats, two-column

I want the image to occupy both columns for good resolution within a two-column document and also want the text in two column format. I used following command, but it overlaps with the text in other column.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Placing Imaging in LaTex}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{PTS.eps}}
       \caption{Figure PTS}
    \end{figure}
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?
\end{document}
```

What should I do?
**using figure* I could rectify it, but the caption is appearing too left.**

Comment: you want `figure*` for two-column figure

Comment: It worked but the caption is more towards left.

Comment: Perhaps you did something wrong, if you show what you did someone could help. Every question should have a small example document from `\documentclass` to `\end{docuemnt}` that demonstrates the problem. You can use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so we don't need your actual image.

Comment: \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing}
\section{INTRODUCTION}

Comment: you can edit the question rather than adding code in comments (but it's not very useful unless it is a complete document that demonstrates the problem)

Comment: I have edited the question and included dummy document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is designed to follow IEEE design style which is mostly left justified, however it has a conference option that uses centred captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\title{Placing Imaging in LaTex}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?

    \begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{PTS.eps}}

       \caption{Figure PTS}
    \end{figure*}
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?
would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?would like to make a list of math exercises. Formatting that intend this list is as follows. The first half of the page I would write in a single column. From the second half of the page into two columns I write normally.

Is there any resource (package LaTeX command or setting in the preamble of the LaTeX document) to write a document possessing simultaneously (and even on the same page) text in single column and double column?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you may want your picture look like. If you need to center the figure caption as well, just add `\usepackage{caption}` in your preamble below `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`.

[image]

I used the following MWE for brevity:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\begin{document}

\title{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing}
\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{MyPTS.eps} 
  \caption{Figure PTS}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[4-19]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the function of \lipsum?

Comment: It is to fill with random text to have the look of a real written paper. It is usually used for testing purposes.

Comment: That's the same as my answer except it has a left aligned caption which the OP said in comments did not want.